# UICollectionViewをタップしてデフォルトの写真アプリのような拡大表示

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

CollectionViewCellをタップした時に、iPhoneデフォルトの写真アプリでCellをタップした時みたいな、画像位置から全画面サイズに拡大する画面の実装を組みたいです。

例えば以下のようにしてUICollectionViewのcellにImageViewを乗せて画像を表示させるとして

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 4;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"];
    UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"];

    NSMutableArray *images = @[image1,image2,image3,image4];
    UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //ここで処理をすると思うのですが…
}
```

上のcellタップ時のメソッドでなんらかの処理をすると思うのですが、さっぱり分かりません。

どんな情報でもお持ちの方教えて頂けるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

方法としては、いくらでもあります。

1. 本来の`animated`を`NO`にして独自でアニメーションを書く方法
2. カスタムセグエを使う方法（iOS5〜）
3. `UIViewController`のカスタム画面遷移を使う方法（iOS7〜）

いまから実装するのであれば、3でやるのがオススメです。

ただし、いわゆるモーダルで表示する場合と、`UINavigationController`や`UITabbarController`の遷移を変更したい場合で記述が変わったり、インタラクティブ画面遷移を実装しようとするとちょっと大変かもしれません。

---

[片道UIViewControllerTransition](https://gist.github.com/glayash/fb00ac792e6b3625cf12)

`StoryBoard`がないので解りにくいかもしれませんが（特に複雑なことはやってないです）、`UICollectionView`の画像を拡大して次の`UIViewController`にシームレスに表示するようなコードサンプル（`UINavigationController`使用時）です。

Comment: 僕もpinterest風に選択したコレクションアイテムが画面全体に拡大される画面遷移を実装したのですが、quesera2さんがいうようにUIViewControllerのカスタム画面遷移を使いました。その時はこのソースコードを参考にさせてもらいました。
https://github.com/xhzengAIB/PinterestAnimator

Comment: pintrest風のオープンソースで、日本語で解説されているものを見つけました。
ご参考に。
(http://tech.recruit-mp.co.jp/mobile/custom-zooming-transition-animation)